# How to define an IntentFilter for a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

So I am attempting to make an application that will show a toast message when every a text message is received. I want the application to only show the toast, and I currently using this code to show it, but I get an exception error when the application runs. I am using this code

```
BroadcastReceiver BR = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText( context, "testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }
    };


    IntentFilter filter = new  IntentFilter();

    registerReceiver(BR, filter);
```

I'm pretty sure it's the intent filter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: you should better post your logcat too.

Comment: What exception error? Post the stack trace.

Comment: post your logcat error. its difficult to help with the info you provided..

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the entry of your broadcastreceiver in manifest then add the intent filter as we add for our activities.It is possible on runtime too.

Answer (score 0):

You should create seperate class which extends BroadcastReceiver
and then override onRecieve method.

Here, AlarmMain.this is main class and
OneShotAlarm.class which extends BroadcaseReceiver :

```
@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText( context, "testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }
```

You can call onRecieve() as per following:

```
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(AlarmMain.this, OneShotAlarm.class);
operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmMain.this, 0, intentAlarm, 0);

alarmManager  = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, objDate.getTime(), operation);
```

You can try following but it is optional (include following tag into AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<receiver 
    android:name="com.android.alarm.OneShotAlarm"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```